# springframework 3.2 Servlet 3 Async Support

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I was reading about the new springframework 3.2 feature, Servlet 3 Async support here:

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support

and I have a question.

The blog article indicates that spring now supports:

1. Controller returning a Callable
2. The callable gets invoked in a background thread (`TaskExecutor`)
3. The response remains open (`request.startAsync()`).

The stated motivation is to avoid eating up all of the web container threads. However, my understanding is this:

1. The web container thread pool is tunable.
2. There is a hard limit on that thread pool because it's preferable to degrade serving rather than bring down the process by exhausting all resources (as would happen with, say, an unbounded thread pool and large enough number of requests).
3. The point of servlet-3/comet is to limit the number of open threads while not limiting the number of open connections to a web server (because threads are expensive and sockets are cheap)

So given this, the feature Spring is proposing makes very little sense to me. Are they not just hacking an unbounded thread pool on top of the container's bounded pool? Does that not miss the point of limiting the number of threads?

Comment: more of a discussion than a question, no?

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding the intent. Perhaps there is a different use case that I don't understand.